# Bad php codes can cause this(Error:Connection timed out) type of errors in FTP?

Tags: php, mysql, ftp, phpmyadmin, filezilla

Sometimes when i am trying to connect to my server through filezilla i am getting this error at the same time my site and phpmyadmin is also down and getting errors like this `mysql error: MySQL server has gone away` or some times `too many connections`. It was working fine for last two days. 2 days before i altered  tables in my database added some code in my .inc files (ie, php code) after that only i am having this problem. But some times i can connect to server and both my site and phpadmin is also loaded. ***I would like to know whether bad php codes can cause this(`Error:Connection timed out`) type of errors in FTP?***  Please help me..

***SOLVED***

> Problem was with the server and they have corrected it. Thanks a lot
>   to all of you who responded to my question

Comment: probably issue at your host, contact them and ask what's up.

Comment: @MakuraYami Its my clients server they told they have restarted the server. but having the same problem. They are telling it may be the coding problem.

Comment: So you are getting issues with FTP and MySQL and HTTP servers? The only thing I can think of in terms of PHP code being root cause is if either a) it's hogging up all memory or b) hogging up all available connections to all three servers.  First step in troubleshooting: turn off the new code and see if problem goes away. If it does, add troublesome code to question.

Comment: @ Anthony i just roll back new code now i am getting error like this `#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured) ` in my phpmyadmin and `Database error:

Link-ID == false, connect failed

mysql error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (11)` in my site

Comment: Try a different server, perhaps? What is the spec/OS of the server? Is it a VPS/dedi or a shared PHP host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your code is establishing too many MySQL connections, can you add the code to your question to confirm? (Do you have a DB connection in a loop by any chance?)

Regarding post-rollback errors, as you have not stated what you have tried, here is a slew of possible solutions.

- [MySQL #2002 forum post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,64808,64808#msg-64808) - A few possible solutions here.
- [linuxquestions forum post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-lib-mysql-mysql-sock-281557/) - (setting 'socket =  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' in my.cf)
- ['Solve: Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket /tmp/mysql.sock'](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/762/solve-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock/)

The basic problem is most likely that you do not have the socket set correctly, check where the .sock is and what is currently set to in your settings.

Aside: You could go for a clean install of LAMP / XAMPP / whatever, may end up being quicker if possible assuming you can't fix the issue itself.